# How to create virtualenv in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: command-line, python3, virtualenv

I have installed `virtualenv`:

```
pip3 install --user virtualenv
```

Then I was trying to create an environment for my folder with the next command:

```
folder_name$ python -m venv ll_env
```

But instead of the desired result I've got an error:

```
__The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not available.
On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install python3-venv package using the following command.

apt-get install python3-venv

You may need to use sudo with that command.
After installing the python3-venv package, recreate your virtual environment.__
```

However despite thr error `virtualenv` folder named `ll_env` created.

I have no idea why I receive this error. I'm new to Linux. I tried to check if `virtualenv` exists on system with this command:

```
pip3 show virtualenv
```

And I got:

```
Name: virtualenv
Version: 16.0.0
Summary: Virtual Python Environment builder
Home-page: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/
Author: Ian Bicking
Author-email: ianb@colorstudy.com
License: MIT
Location: /home/just_maverick/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires:
```

Comment: And don't keep us in suspense! Have you or have you not followed the request of your friendly Python and tried to install the package `python3-venv` by running the command `sudo apt-get install python3-venv`?

Comment: No, I ran that  command:  

` pip install --user virtualenv`

Comment: have you tried `virtualenv foldername` yet...?

Comment: So the poor Python tried to obey your command, and it could not, and it asked you to help it by installing a piece of software on your computer. How can you be so stone-hearted and refuse the request of your Python?

Comment: Do what the error message tells you to do and you won't see that error message anymore.

Comment: I read that installing packages with sudo it's a bad practice, and therefore I did not follow to system's advices.

Comment: *"I read that installing packages with sudo it's a bad practice":* citation needed.

Comment: @AlexP What is clearly false requires no citation.  `apt-get install python3-venv
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
`

Comment: @karel that looks like an answer to me....

Comment: @ElderGeek: I believe that the inquirer has indeed read *something* which mentioned that it's bad practice to install some things with `sudo`, maybe referring to Python modules. I believe that they are in confusion about what they have read, where it applies, and why. That's why I wanted to elicit a remembrance of said reading.

Comment: @AlexP I understand the motivation, and didn't intend to indicate that the OP hadn't been misled, but IMHO obtaining the source may have a similar unintended consequence as naming a school shooter.  Adding to the fame of a con artist isn't something I would encourage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As pointed out by [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/q/1040916/#comment1695440_1040916)  by [karel.](https://askubuntu.com/users/94914/karel)

The answer to your question is actually **in** your question:

```
__The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not available.
On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install python3-venv package using the following command.

apt-get install python3-venv

You may need to use sudo with that command.
```

To clarify, simply issue the command `sudo apt-get install python3-venv` or `sudo apt install python3-venv` either of which will install the [python3-venv package,](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=python3-venv) provided of course that you've [enabled the universe repository first.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

```
After installing the python3-venv package, recreate your virtual environment.__
```

Good programmers will often provide hints or outright solutions to problems that are likely to occur. This is an example of the latter.

Comment: It was almost obvious to me that I needed to execute command with sudo. But as a beginner I tried to follow advice of one experienced? programmer and like grim death intended to avoid granting root access. It was not very smart, but I was misled with it.

Comment: @AlexStelmakh You've put your finger on the reason I'm obsessed with testing. Although I've done some programming over the years with several (many now obsolete) languages, I'm first and foremost a troubleshooter who has a firm belief that change is the only constant. I'm glad my answer was useful to you.  Cheers! ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the anwser. you need to remove a dash - from the `sudo apt install python-3-venv` should be `sudo apt install python3-venv`, then it works :)

Comment: @minisaurus Nice catch, feel free to help out by editing any errors such as the aforementioned that you find on the site.